# Is it possible to using expression on Spring SecurityMetadataSource?

Tags: spring, spring-security

i want to manage url authorization by Database. So, i'm implement Security MetadataSource. It was perfect except cann't using expression.

below is my code and xml settings.

xml

```
<beans:bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager" />
    <beans:property name="securityMetadataSource" ref="securityMetadataSource" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
                <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:property name="allowIfAllAbstainDecisions" value="false" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="securityMetadataSource" class="my.package.CustomSecurityMetadataSource">
</beans:bean>
```

java

```
public class CustomSecurityMetadataSource implements FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource {

    @Override
    public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAttributes(Object object) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        FilterInvocation fi = (FilterInvocation) object;

        String url = fi.getRequestUrl();
        HttpServletRequest request = fi.getHttpRequest();

        // TODO get url authorization from db and caching
        String[] roles = new String[] { "ROLE_ANONYMOUS", "ROLE_USER"};
        return SecurityConfig.createList(roles);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAllConfigAttributes() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return FilterInvocation.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }
}
```

i want to using expression like `hasAnyRole("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER")`.

how can i use expression?

Comment: Have you found the solution?